# UHD not supported yet 4K resolutions are selectable?

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, powerdvd

I've just switched my Blu-ray drive to one that can handle UHD discs, yet when I try to play one in PowerDVD I get an error saying that the disc can't be played on the computer and to check that the GPU meets the system requirements.

The graphics card is a: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070 SUPER connected via a DisplayPort cable

It seems strange that it doesn't work when I've got Windows 10 displaying in a 4K resolution and the graphics card is one that can handle ray tracing.

I've just tried doing a fresh/clean install of the graphics drivers, but that hasn't made any difference

Answer (score 1):

From the [official CyberLink web page](https://www.cyberlink.com/support-center/faq/content?id=19144), the requirements to play UHD Blu-Ray discs on a computer are as follows (summarized):

> **OS:**   Microsoft Windows 10 (64-bit with 2017 Oct. updates)
>
> **CPU:**   Intel 7th to 10th gen Core CPU that supports Intel SGX
>
> **Graphics Processor:**   Intel 7th to 10th generation Core iGPU (Intel HD Graphics 630 or Intel Iris Graphics 640).    UHD Blu-ray
> playback is only supported on that graphics processor (i.e., not on
> dGPUs or eGPUs).
>
> **Motherboard:**   Motherboard must support Intel SGX and be enabled in BIOS/UEFI settings.   Motherboard HDMI/DisplayPort output must be
> HDCP 2.2 compliant.
>
> **Display:**   The display device must have HDMI 2.0a or DisplayPort 1.3 or above inputs, and be directly (i.e. without adapters, splitters, etc.) connected to the computer with an HDMI 2.0a/DP 1.3
> certified cable.   UHD screen resolution is recommended.   Note: HDR
> requires HDMI 2.0a/DP 1.4.
>
> **Memory:**   4 GB or above
>
> **Other:**   Compatible ODD.   CyberLink PowerDVD itself.   Internet connection.   Windows Media Player 9 and Intel ME > 11.6.0.1126
> installed.

For your particular case, you cannot output UHD Blu-Ray content over an Nvidia GPU.

Answer (score 0):

You might need another player.

The Cyberlink article
[How Do I Set Up an Ultra HD Blu-ray Movie Compatible Platform?](https://www.cyberlink.com/stat/help/powerdvd/22/pc-mode/enu/98_01_14_how_to_play_uhdbd.html)
says this:

> Ultra HD Blu-ray playback requires a CPU that supports Intel SGX, a
> hardware enforcement method used to protect the video content during
> playback.
>
> Please be advised that SGX is being removed from the latest generation
> CPUs, and phased out of the required drivers. Therefore, Ultra HD
> Blu-ray playback on the latest generation of CPUs will not be
> supported.

Your CPU might be too recent for PowerDVD to do UHD.

Comment: Your answer is not totally right. It can be the case that their CPU is incompatible, although the age of their GPU can be consistent with a compatible processor. What is certainly the case is that UHD Blu-ray content **must** be played through the Intel iGPU (see my answer for details).

Comment: @SpacePhoenix: Try using the [VLC player](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/). If it can't play the disc then your hardware is not compatible. If you wish to watch Bluray, you might do better to buy a player device.

Comment: VLC by default cannot play Blu-ray discs (of any kind). It needs AACS libraries (which VideoLAN distributes) and the decryption keys for the discs (which VideoLAN does not distribute). The availability and legality of said keys depends on your applicable legislation. Needless to say, this is not the "official" way to play the discs (PowerDVD is).

Comment: @ComputerUser121212: You're not up to date - VLC can now play Blu-Ray. See [How VLC Play Blu-Ray on Windows 10](https://multimedia.easeus.com/video-converter-tips/vlc-play-blu-ray.html) and [libbluray](https://www.videolan.org/developers/libbluray.html).

Comment: Yes, VLC does play Blu-ray movies by default, but, without the keys it **will not** decrypt any encrypted (that is, almost all commercial Blu-ray discs) discs. In the same library you link (and in the libaacs aswell) it clearly says that they **do not** circumvent DRM. Be aware that the license you buy when you buy a Blu-ray disc does only allow for playback in specific approved devices. (**NOT ACTUAL LEGAL ADVICE**)

Comment: @ComputerUser121212: Nevertheless, for example [DVDFab Blu-ray Copy](https://www.dvdfab.cn/resource/blu-ray/how-to-decrypt-blu-ray) claims the ability to de-DRM an encrypted Blu-Ray, and it's not the only one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148298/discussion-between-computeruser121212-and-harrymc).